# Python, Fernet encryption, use salt as a second password?

Tags: python, cryptography

I followed a simple guide for encrypting a password from https://nitratine.net/blog/post/encryption-and-decryption-in-python/

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

password_provided = "password" # This is input in the form of a string
password = password_provided.encode() # Convert to type bytes
salt = b'salt_' # CHANGE THIS - recommend using a key from os.urandom(16), must be of type bytes
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    length=32,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=100000,
    backend=default_backend()
)
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password)) # Can only use kdf once
```

My question is: can I use salt as a second password? In order to generate key and decrypt a message user'd have to input both password and salt. Is this safe and a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

No, not really, because users are likely to use the same password combination in similar situations. That makes it possible to compare the identical hashes. It is much better to create one good secure password instead of asking for two, as most users will be annoyed if you ask for two.

As for e.g. protection against rainbow tables: if the password is unique enough than it will help against rainbow tables. But as I've indicated, I don't think it is good practice; please keep salt and password separated.

If you want to use the salt to create multiple keys from the same PBKDF then I suggest you use a separate Key Based KDF on the output of PBKDF. HKDF or HKDF-Expand would make the most sense.

Comment: So exposed key + strong password > hidden key & password & salt?

Comment: Having to enter both password and salt means that you don't have to store key anywhere which looks appealing.
Moreover if you use key, a third party would have to guess just over single password, whilst guessing over both password and salt makes it twice harder.
This provided both password and salt are strong enough.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that. If you use PBKDF2 to generate a key for a cipher, then you can store the salt with the ciphertext. Otherwise if you need just a password hash for authentication then you can store the salt with the password hash. Can you explain a situation where there is no other data that needs to be stored?